# How do I properly include textAngular in meanjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm writing an angular app that requires a wysiwyg editor, and while doing some research, I came across [textAngular](https://github.com/fraywing/textAngular).  It looks like what I want, but when I insert the `<text-angular></text-angular>` directive in my html, the editor looks very broken:
[image: Broken textangular]

This is what it is supposed to look like:
[image: Working textAngular]

Am I missing a dependency for this library?  Why don't most of the buttons have any icons?  The js console is not reporting any errors.  What can I try to get this working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out, the github page says you need to include font-awesome, so I did that and it worked.